# Dynamics CRM : Add Multiple address in Account Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have a scenario where I need to add multiple Address to Account. I am using Dynamics 365 online instance and my current implementation for Account Entity form looks like below,
[image]

My requirement is I need to put multiple address sections here to enter Regional Office details. I have made some changes in the form to input 2 Regional Address. But for some account, there would be multiple regional addresses which we cant predict.
[image]

Is there any option in dynamics to add multiple addresses like above, so that we don't need to add more sections rather user can click on (+ Symbol) to add this section to enter address details.

Comment: CRM has native child address entity relationship which will store multiple address for a parent account.. [are you not using it?](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/theartformofcrm/archive/2016/09/24/address-entity). in your case, Each address Section is going to have one multi line text box or what?

Comment: Thanks for the comments Vinoth. I just started learning CRM 2 months back and not familiar with all out of the box features and functionalities. How to use CRM native child entity relationship in my case. Also, the above Address section contains multiline textbox(Default address section).

Comment: Check the link in my first comment.. that should answer you.. otherwise you can have multiple multi line textbox hidden in the form, show/hide based on some add more address button (+) or something like that..(I don’t recommend this as it’s going to have unnecessary denormalized multi line fields in the same Account record)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Out of the box Address entity (relationship available only to Account/Contact).

Like explained in this [blog](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/theartformofcrm/archive/2016/09/24/address-entity), Enable the navigation in Account form editor to see the associated view of Address in Account record.

> Open your solution and edit the Account form, Select Navigation and then double click addresses - Then "Save & Publish"

[image]

Additionally, you can add subgrid of address view in Account form, but known [product bug](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/195144) will not allow users to create new address from subgrid (+) button due to limitations like quick create not available for Address entity and lookup of customer missing in Address form. So you have to train users to use associated view to add new address.