# Why are the field sets for Account addresses contained in the Account table and not in a separate table?

Tags: database, database-design, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dataverse

Looking through the Microsoft documentation on the Common Data Model and Microsoft Dataverse as well as Powerapps itself I found the contents of the Account table. This table contains two sets of address fields. Microsoft documentation suggests that one of them is the main address, and the second may be an alternative address, e.g. for billing.

Documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-model/schema/core/applicationcommon/account
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-model/

Shouldn't the Account table contain only the basic information about Account, and in a separate table linked to Account shouldn't we contain addresses linked to Account and link these two records with a parent-child relationship?

Will anyone be able to explain to me what is behind this approach?

Comment: My opinion: traditional Model-Driven apps usually show the fields of one table at a time on the screen (there are exceptions). Having a proper normalized data model often comes as a detriment to UI & navigation so we see a lot of design trade-offs like this. There is also an Address table (used to store multiple/secondary addresses) that you can decide to use instead.

Comment: I believe for some other purpose like shipping label/mail merge template - these de-normalized fields available in same record and default two address child records (billing/shipping) will be created for each record as well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47974020/7920473 check this

Answer (score 1):

Common Data Model derives from the original Entities (now called Tables) defined inside Dynamics CRM. The model described there is not "normalized" from a database point of view (Dynamics CRM now called Dataverse uses SQL Server under the hood), so as you found you have the addresses fields (now called Columns) inside the Account.

Keep in mind that the Common Data Model is one of the possible approaches, you can for example create a custom table to store the addresses and link it to the Account or create custom tables to store the accounts and the addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I don't have specific Dynamics experience, so there's a possibility that I'm wrong with my interpretation.

Neither of the links you shared mention the word 'table', or suggest a relational data model.

My take from these links is that they describe a format/schema, but don't specifically say anything about how the underlying data is stored.

So if you want to use a RDBMS and store the the business/mailing address in an 'addresses' table, I don't think there's anything here that suggests you can't.

Comment: I may have misrepresented the problem. Dataverse implements the Common data model as a relational database schema. The Common data model schema itself involves holding two sets of Account addresses on an Account table rather than a separate address table. It has always seemed to me that for Account addresses it is better to keep them in a separate related table. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Describing in addition: Each set of fields for addresses contains approximately 10 fields. That is, each customer record will contain 20 address fields. Looking at this architecturally - shouldn't this data be in a sub-table?